# database design for storing individual users' items

Tags: database-design

I am trying to make an application which users can have their own account
For the account, I have an single table and now I would like to add a function which
allows users to items in to their account

For example, user A want to add item A ,B ,C ,D to his account,
then on the database should have 4 rows of new data
Also there are no limit on the maximum number of item users can add.

My question will be how the item should I store on the database.
In a single table or a new table for each of the users?
Will the data retrieving time be very slow if there are lots of users with items?
And will many tables in a single database affect my works?

Comment: how many users, what data type and how large are the columns A,B,C,D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general rule of thumb is that you will have a table for each *type* of thing that you are recording information about.  Each *instance* of a thing will be a record in a table.

It would probably<sup>*</sup> be a terrible idea to have one table per user.  Have one table with `USERS` and one table with `THINGS`.  In the `THINGS` table you will have a *foreign key* which is a column containing a `user_id` that points at the `USERS` record for the owner of the thing.

Relational databases are designed specifically to make this kind of structure easy and fast to work with.  You shouldn't<sup>*</sup> ever need to worry about how many users there are or how many things they have.

<sup>*</sup> NOTE: Your requirements are very sparse.  These are rules of thumb.